# uploading, resize and get dimensions of the new image

Tags: php, image

input type file - uploading an image

```
$arr = $_FILES['inpfile'];
$filename = $arr['name'];
$tempname = $arr['tmp_name'];

$arr = getimagesize($tempname);
$origw = $arr[0]; // original width
$origh = $arr[1]; // original height

if ($mime == 'image/jpeg') {$newimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempname);}
elseif ($mime == 'image/png') {$newimg = imagecreatefrompng($tempname);}
elseif ($mime == 'image/gif') {$newimg = imagecreatefromgif($tempname);}

if($origw > 960) {
    $newimg = imagescale($newimg, 960);
}
```

Now I need dimensions of the new image:

```
$arr = getimagesize($newimg);
$endw = $arr[0];
$endh = $arr[1];
```

Warning:

`getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given`

Any help?

Comment: You need to save image to the filesystem and then use image path as an argument for getimagesize function.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze, it works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get width and height of the image **resource** (in your case `$newimg` has a **resource** type) you can use [`imagesx`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php)/[`imagesy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php) functions respectively:

```
$endw = imagesx($newimg);
$endh = imagesy($newimg);
```